# Generating monthly report mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which there are 5 columns,

```
id (auto incrementing number), titleId, version, created_at
```

A combination of titleId and version is always unique. I want to find out for each day for the past 1 month, how many unique titleIds were present along with the count of how many entries per day. This is because on a given day there might be multiple versions of the same titleId.

```
select count(*) from titles where  created_at >= '2019-08-12 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2019-08-13 00:00:00' will give me total number of titles which came on 12th August
```

and

```
select count(distinct titleId) from titles where  created_at >= '2019-08-12 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2019-08-13 00:00:00'
```

will give me the count of unique titles on the 12th August. Is there a way for me to generate the data for the past 30/60 days?

I know I can run this command manually 30 times by changing the date to get the numbers, but was wondering if there is a better way to do this in mysql

Comment: Is there always an entry for every day?

Comment: @Nick yes there is an entry daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is an entry every day, this query should give you the data for each day for the last 30:

```
select date(created_at) as cdate, count(distinct titleId) as cnt
from titles
where created_at >= cur_date() - interval 30 day
group by cdate
```

Comment: Wow works great. Is it possible  to group for 2 days instead of a day, i.e. aggregate the same data over 2 months, but instead of per day results, i want to know over 2 days.

Comment: @user1692342 you could do that by creating a grouping variable that was 2 days long, something along the lines of `DATEDIFF(CUR_DATE(), created_at) DIV 2` might work